# Can I check for iOS version update from my app?

Tags: ios

Can I check if there is an iOS version update available from my app? (with both objective c and swift)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the guides on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in order to better understand your question and provide you with even better answers.

Comment: @cat Apple already provides a notification if there is a new update available for the app. But can you please let us know why are you want this feature within the app itself?  Welcome in iOS stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the requirement to have like this.. You can **create a webservice to check latest iOS version and call it from your code**. By this way you can implement this functionality.

Check current version of OS using code

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion]
```

Problem is you will have the time to update the db whenever an update comes in iOS version.

Comment: This is the way to do this, but I really doubt that this is a thing you want to be doing.

Comment: let him do so if needed.. there is not alternative way right